# Should the iOS slide out menu link to all features or should it avoid duplicates?

Tags: gui-design, ios, menu, information-architecture

On my home screen, I'm linking to a few of my main features and putting the rest in my slide out menu. I'm wondering if I should list the features available in my home page on the menu as well. It's duplicative and that's not great. But shouldn't the menu contain all the available features on an app?

Would love to hear your opinions.

Comment: Pictures are worth thousands and thousands of words. They certainly help us get a notion of what we should have in our heads.

Answer (score 1):

Android developers actually started this design pattern quite a while ago. In the jelly bean release Google actually made this a stock feature in the android SDK.

The reasoning for explaining this is because Google and all of their geniuses working in the android team have come up with some good design guidelines for "navigation drawers".

- they should be swipe to open.
- should provide top level navigation to the most important screens in your app.
- they are no place for clutter ( ie social buttons, unimportant functions)
- may be used for user profile control, containing a photo and some functions.
- keep it simple.

A good rule of thumb for menus like this is keep it simple. It might be complex; nothing wrong with that but it shouldn't be confusing.

Don't get me wrong though have fun with it! Just remember that it's called a navigation drawer for a reason.

Edit: [Here's a great 50 minute video specifically on navigation drawers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5COhlbpIbY)

Answer (score 0):

The menu items for the slide-out should remain consistent across your app. Having a different menus will only end up confusing your users. Thus the list should be the same regardless of section.

For the featured list on the home page, I'd explore expanding these items to differentiate from their slide-out menu counterparts. A short description or maybe a relevant image to go with the item.